# How to connect android device using ADB CONNECT over Wi-Fi using IPV6?

Tags: android, adb, ipv6

I need to connect my device with laptop over Wi-Fi using ADB CONNECT through IPV6, but getting "Unable to connect" message.

Using IPV4 (Public IP) every thing is working very well, but I need to connect device using IPV6 only.

Anyone can help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to use `IPV6` to connect to the `adbd` on the device until you upgrade it to Android 7.0

`adbd` in all Android versions before that use `AF_INET` address family. `adbd` in Android 7.0 uses `AF_INET6`

Comment: Has Google documented this somewhere?

Comment: @AlexP. Okay. I'll try with 7.0.

Comment: I don't have 15 minutes - or 15 hours! - to go digging through the source code.