# Enable Android wireless debugging via ADB with IPv6 address

Tags: android, adb

- I am using a Google Pixel 4 XL with Android 12
- The wireless network interface has two IPv6 addresses bound to it
- I have enabled **Developer Options**
- In the **Developer Options** menu, I have enabled the **Wireless Debugging** setting
- When I click into the **Wireless Debugging** child menu, only an IPv4 address appears

On my Windows 11 system, I try to use `adb` to connect to the device, but it seems the syntax is wrong, or `adb` just does not support IPv6 addresses at all.

```
PS > adb connect [2605:590c0:c4e0:901:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff]:42575
cannot resolve host '2605:590c0:c4e0:901:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff' and port 42575: No such host is known. (11001)
PS > adb connect 2605:590c0:c4e0:901:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:42575
no host in '2605:590c0:c4e0:901:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:42575'
```

**Question**: How do I enable **Wireless Debugging** for the IPv6 addresses that the device has been allocated, and connect using `adb`?

Comment: Have you checked on the device if port 42575 is open and if it listens on IPv4 only or also on IPv6? Connect the device via USB and check this then you know if it can work at all.

Comment: A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39388866/150978

Comment: I played around with this some more, and it does actually work. I'll have to try to reproduce this error again, but as of this moment, I don't see anything wrong with my original command. I'm confused, but will share more once I find out.

Comment: @Robert so, what's interesting about this is that the **Wireless Debugging** screen on Android only shows the network interface's IPv4 address. However, if you go back to the Status screen and use either the "main" or "temporary" IPv6 addresses associated with the device, it does actually work. I need to go back and see what I did differently from my original post.